# plesk AWS automation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have setup plesk to run through ssh and it works awesome, the only problem is that I have to run the script manually everyday.  This should be automated.  Just putting in this command "aws s3 sync [localdirectory] [s3://[S3Directory]" in the scheduled tasks section on a domain doesn't allow for the credentials to load.  I am thinking that there should be a relatively easy solution to automate this.  I have setup php for it as well so if there is a short script that would handle the same thing I would be interested in seeing an example.

Comment: Can you paste what script you run manually?

Comment: It starts with "aws configure"  it then asks for the Access Key Id and the secret key and then I can run the code above without issues